# No internet access on Windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003-r2

I need some help resolving Server 2003 issue I have been having. I inherited the situation from my predecessor. I have full LAN connectivity on Server 2003 however, I am not able to connect to internet on it to update antivirus, Windows etc.  I tried pinging 8.8.8.8 and all requests timed out, tracert for 8.8.8.8 also timed out.  All users are able to access internet without an issue, the problem only lies with the Server.  I am not sure what else to do in resolving this issue which has been bugging me now.  Anyone can help please. Thanks

Comment: Does it have an IP address? Are the routes and default router correct?

Comment: Provide us a ipconfig /all and give us your router IP.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was out of office for a while.  The server has a static IP address and goes through a firewall/router.  All the workstations in the office connect to the internet without any issues and also connect to the same server without any problems either.  The problem is only on the server whereas it doesn't connect to the internet. Whenever I open a browser for any site it says it's not connected to the internet.  Even the AV is unable to pull necessary updates.  I am thinking it's some setting which I am missing but can't seem to figure out which.

Comment: The firewall/router is identified as the gateway in the server/s TCP/IP config.